# How to add tags to file storage, queue storage and table storage created in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-queues, azure-files

I have created all three, table storage, queue storage, and file storage within Microsoft Azure. Now I wish to add tags to those resources. I could add tags to Storage Account, the basic requirement for the above resources, but not for the above three resources.

My question is: Can we add tags to these resources? If yes how, and can we do it using APIs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't.

See  [Tag support for Azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/tag-support#microsoftstorage):

[image]

Comment: +1 I had gone through the documentation, but I felt I had missed something. Anyone, please add to above if I have missed something.

Comment: @OMKARHIRVE It is the fact, the doc is clear, `The column labeled Supports tags indicates whether the resource type has a property for the tag. `

Comment: @OMKARHIRVE Or may I know what let you feel miss something?

Comment: Wanted to be 100% sure about it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @OMKARHIRVE So this is just your intuition? If the official documents are not credible, what else is credible? Even if this is not the result you want, but I think you should accept the fact.

Comment: Sure, could you just help me differentiate between Queue/Table/File Storage metadata and tags, Looks similar to me. as both are key-value pairs

Comment: @OMKARHIRVE You can use metadata to store additional values with a storage resource. These additional metadata values are for your own purposes only, and do not affect how the resource behaves, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-container-properties-metadata?WT.mc_id=docs-azuredevtips-micrum). If you need to know other more details about it, I recommend you to ask it in another post, it is not related to the topic of this post, stackoverflow avoid to ask the different questions in one post.